# PHP SQLITE3 query as a function

Tags: php, function, sqlite

I have this part of code working fine:

```
$array_stats_raw = $db->query($query);
$array_statistics[$name] = $array_stats_raw->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
```

However I have many different queries that I have to pass in the same code so I am trying to put it in a function and call the function instead of repeating this code many times.

I tried the following:

```
function sqlite_query123($dbhandle,$query1,$name) 
    { 
        $result = $dbhandle->query($query1);
        $result1[$name] = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        return $result1; 
    } 

$array_statistics[$name] = sqlite_query123($db, $query, $name);
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry for asking a novice question but I feel like I am missing something simple and can't figure it out what?

Comment: [`sqlite_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php) is already a function. Try naming it something else.

Comment: changed it to sqlite_query123 both the function name and call... still no good.

Comment: You haven't actually described the problem at all. What is it that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following also worked:

```
function sqlite_query123($dbhandle,$query1,$name) 
{ 
    $result = $dbhandle->query($query1);
    $result1[$name] = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    return $result1[name]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase it is not a typo in the question, you misspelt $result as $results :

```
function sqlite_query123($dbhandle,$query1,$name) 
    { 
        $result = $dbhandle->query($query1);
        $result1[$name] = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        return $result1; 
    }
```

UPDATE :
Try this

```
function sqlite_query123($dbhandle,$query1,$name) 
        { 
            $result = $dbhandle->query($query1);
            return $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        }
```

Comment: Thx, fixed the typo and it is still not working, updated the original question as well.